# What do I need to do to correct my WebLogic Universal Pooled Connection Data Source JNDI binding error?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

The call to simply establish what I'm referring to as a JNDI unbound WebLogic Universal Connection Pool (UCP) data source ***jndiUnboundDataSource()*** works and is able to create & return a usable database connection.

The ***jndiBindDataSource()*** method is throwing the following exception:

***Unexpected exception: java.rmi.RemoteException: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$23***

The ***jndiBindDataSource()*** method is attempting to create a UCP data source and then bind it to a JNDI context... the intent being that the ***jndiBoundDataSource()*** method would be able to retrieve the bound UCP data source from the JNDI context. At this point I haven't gotten to test ***jndiBoundDataSource()*** because ***jndiBindDataSource()*** is failing.

WebLogic 12.1.3 - Universal Connection Pool ConnectionClassFactory:

***com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource***

You should be able to recreate the error from the following source:

```
package com.corporate.experiments;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.ValidConnection;

public class WebLogicUniversalConnectionPool extends HttpServlet
{
    @SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.serialversionuid-stale") private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCP/ds_annotation.htm#BABEDEJJ
    // http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCP/ds_annotation.htm#BABDBHCD

    /**
     *  The name element uniquely identifies a DataSource and is registered with JNDI.
     *  The value specified in the name element begins with a namespace scope.
     *
     *  Java EE Data Source Naming Scopes:
     *
     *  java:comp - Names in this namespace have component visibility.
     *  java:module - Names in this namespace are shared by all components in a module, for example, the EJB components defined in an a ejb-jar.xml file.
     *  java:app - Names in this namespace are shared by all components and modules in an application, for example, the application-client, web, and EJB components in an .ear file.
     *  java:global - Names in this namespace are shared by all the applications in the server.
     *
     *  Java EE Data Source Naming Conventions:
     *
     *  Component visibility:
     *  ---------------------
     *  appname @ modulename @ componentname @ dsname
     *
     *  Module visibility:
     *  ------------------
     *  appname @ modulename @ dsname
     *
     *  Application visibility:
     *  -----------------------
     *  appname @ dsname
     *
     *  Global visibility:
     *  ------------------
     *  dsname
     */

    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_NAME = "app/content";
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_NAMESPACE = "java:" + DATA_SOURCE_NAME;

    /**
     * @param request
     * @param response
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        // http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJUCP/connect.htm#JJUCP8139

        try
        {
            jndiUnboundDataSource();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return; // place break point here
        }

        // create a context bound connection pool data source

        try
        {
            jndiBindDataSource(); // Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return; // place break point here
        }

        // get a connection from the bound connection pool data source

        try
        {
            jndiBoundDataSource(); // Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return; // place break point here
        }

        return; // place break point here
    }

    // create a context unbound connection pool data source and get a connection

    private DataSource jndiUnboundDataSource() throws SQLException
    {
        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource();

        validateDataSource(dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    // create a context and bind a connection pool data source

    private DataSource jndiBindDataSource() throws NamingException, SQLException
    {
        InitialContext context = createInitialContext();

        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource();

        validateDataSource(dataSource);

        // Unexpected exception: java.rmi.RemoteException: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$23;

        context.bind(DATA_SOURCE_NAME, dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    // create a context and look up a connection pool data source

    private DataSource jndiBoundDataSource() throws NamingException, SQLException
    {
        InitialContext context = initialContext();

        PoolDataSource poolDataSource = (PoolDataSource) context.lookup(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);

        validateDataSource(poolDataSource);

        return poolDataSource;
    }

    private InitialContext initialContext() throws NamingException
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String> ();

        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7101");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Container");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "development");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "development");

        return new InitialContext(environment);
    }

    private InitialContext createInitialContext() throws NamingException
    {
        InitialContext initialContext = initialContext();

        initialContext.createSubcontext("corporate");

        return initialContext;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException
    {
        PoolDataSource poolDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

        poolDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");

        poolDataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metadata");
        poolDataSource.setUser("root");
        poolDataSource.setPassword("root");

        return poolDataSource;
    }

    private void validateDataSource(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        validateConnection(connection);

        connection.close();
    }

    private void validateConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException
    {       
        if (null == connection)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Null connection: servlet data source namespace \"" + DATA_SOURCE_NAMESPACE + "\"");
        }

        if (!((ValidConnection) connection).isValid())
        {
            throw new SQLException("Invalid connection: servlet data source namespace \"" + DATA_SOURCE_NAMESPACE + "\"");
        }
    }    
}
```

Here's the exception:

```
        Unexpected exception: java.rmi.RemoteException: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$23; nested exception is:

        java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$23
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.copyObject(WLEventContextImpl.java:400)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.bind(WLEventContextImpl.java:279)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
        at com.corporate.experiments.WebLogicUniversalConnectionPool.jndiBindDataSource(WebLogicUniversalConnectionPool.java:123)
        at com.corporate.experiments.WebLogicUniversalConnectionPool.doGet(WebLogicUniversalConnectionPool.java:81)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$23
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.writeObject(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:3015)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.CBVOutputStream.writeObject(CBVOutputStream.java:80)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.JNDIHelper.copyObject(JNDIHelper.java:39)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.copyObject(WLSJNDIEnvironmentImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.copyObject(WLEventContextImpl.java:395)
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: I set up the same data source and successfully tested the same data source within the WebLogic console --- but when I attempt to use this data source via my servlet I get the same error as shown above...

Comment: My interpretation is that the way the data source is defined is OK - but the way I'm referencing it from my application is wonky...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to define a remote datasource.

You can't do that for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) does not extend [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

You don't need to create your own datasource and bind it. You define it using the WebLogic console and give it a JNDI name at the time. WLS then takes care of creating the datasource and binding it for you. All full stack Java EE servers (and Tomcat as well) do it this way.

Comment: That makes sense given the RMI exception - but what am I doing wrong? I can use the data source when I don't put it in JNDI... the implication being that the bind method is somehow interpreting my intent as wanting a remote data source... so, is there a way to tell the bind method to make it local?